# QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor - get headers

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I'm handling requests by installing `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor`. That works fine but `QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo` doesn't have `headers()` property. I'm only able add new header by `QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo::setHttpHeader`. I have googled for solution and found that I can also install `QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler` but seems that it is not working or it isn't what I expected. I'm initializing as suggested in doc:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QWebEngineUrlScheme scheme("myscheme");
    scheme.setSyntax(QWebEngineUrlScheme::Syntax::HostAndPort);
    scheme.setDefaultPort(2345);
    scheme.setFlags(QWebEngineUrlScheme::SecureScheme);
    QWebEngineUrlScheme::registerScheme(scheme);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // installUrlSchemeHandler does not take ownership of the handler.
    MySchemeHandler *handler = new MySchemeHandler(&a);
    QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->installUrlSchemeHandler("myscheme", handler);

    ....
}
```

Header:

```
class MySchemeHandler : public QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MySchemeHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request) override;
};
```

cpp:

```
MySchemeHandler::MySchemeHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler(parent)
{

}

void MySchemeHandler::requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}
```

But `requestStarted` is never triggered

Comment: QWebEngineUrlScheme only handles custom schemes (no http, no https, no qrc) so maybe you are not building the request properly, could you show how you make the requests?

Comment: @eyllanesc Well, the `http://` and `https://` are the ones which I want to intercept (as `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` does). After google more, now I understand how it works. Thought "myscheme" string is some kind of namespace of the scheme but it is actually the scheme. But if I change it to "https://" then my app is chrashing in `installUrlSchemeHandler`. Is it possible to override `http://` and `https://` scheme?

Comment: As I pointed out: *only handles custom schemes (no http, no https, no qrc)*, you can't. I was studying that possibility months ago and I started to analyze the source code and found that QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor cannot intercept http and https (Qt verifies that it is different from those schemes). *Is it possible to override http:// and https:// scheme?* You can do it by modifying the private Qt API

Comment: QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor can intercept http and https, I'm getting such reguests but this object doesn't contain headers. The `QWebEngineUrlRequestJob` has function `requestHeaders()` but I'm not able to intercept http://. It is confusing

Comment: 1) QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo does not provide the headers by default because the Qt developers think that it is not necessary to expose them so if you want them to be accessible then you must request it in a report of a Qt bug and convince it that it is necessary, this would be the solution . 2) On the other hand, QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler has another objective as indicated by the docs: *The QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler class is a base class for handling **custom URL schemes***, so QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler will never work for what you want to do since it was designed for other purposes.

Comment: In simple words with the current Qt API **it is not possible** since QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo does not expose headers, and QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler is designed for other purposes (its goal is not to handle http, https, etc. but custom schemes). I don't understand what confusion you mean.

Comment: By confusing I meant your: "QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor cannot intercept http and https" but that is wrong, I'm getting such urls in `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor::interceptRequest` (but can't get headers as we both agreed). You probably meant `QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler` :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct I meant: *QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler cannot intercept http and https*

Comment: Ok, anyway, thanks for explaining everything